# lists are empty even after making a copy after using for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am using for loop for taking values and storing in 3 lists and using again a for loop to get the values, I have made a copy of each list but still copy also is empty when I am trying to print lists.

I tried making copy of list but didn't work.

```
l_Subjects=[]
l_T_Marks=[]
l_Marks=[]
l_T_Marks1=list(l_Marks)
l_Marks1=l_Marks.copy()
l_Subjects1=l_Subjects.copy()
for i in range(num1):
        Subjects=input("\nType subject name:")
        l_Subjects.append(Subjects)
        while True:
            try:
                T_Marks= int(input(f'Enter total marks for {Subjects}:'))
                l_T_Marks.append(T_Marks)
                while True:
                    Marks = int(input('Enter obtained marks:'))
                    if Marks>T_Marks:
                        print('''\n"Please insert correct marks"''')
                    else:
                        l_Marks.append(Marks)
                        break
            except ValueError:
                print('''\n"Please enter only number"''')
            else:
                break
print(" _________________________________________________________________________")
print("|                                                                         |")
print("|                               Subjects                                  |")
print("|_________________________________________________________________________|")
print("|            Component             |                 Marks                |")
print("|__________________________________|______________________________________|")

for i in list(l_Marks):
    print(f"|              {l_Subjects.pop(0)}                   |           {l_Marks.pop(0)}/{l_T_Marks.pop(0)}                           |")
    print(f"|__________________________________|______________________________________|")

print(l_Marks,l_T_Marks,l_Subjects)
print(l_Marks1,l_Subjects1,l_T_Marks1)
Sum_Marks=(sum(l_Marks1))
Sum_T_Marks=(sum(l_T_Marks1))
```

Comment: your are creating a copy of the empty list at the beginning, then you are taking the value and append to the original list, this will not modify the copied list, that's why your copied lists are printed empty.

Comment: and how can i correct it?

Comment: You can copy the list whenever you finish putting values in it. In your code, you can copy the lists before this line `print(l_Marks,l_T_Marks,l_Subjects)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you used to copy the list,use that code after the for loop(when for loop insert values in lists then make a copy of them),copying lists before for loop will be empty because at that time the lists are empty.i have corrected the code(given below)

```
    l_Subjects=[]
    l_T_Marks=[]
    l_Marks=[]

    for i in range(num1):
            Subjects=input("\nType subject name:")
            l_Subjects.append(Subjects)
            while True:
                try:
                    T_Marks= int(input(f'Enter total marks for {Subjects}:'))
                    l_T_Marks.append(T_Marks)
                    while True:
                        Marks = int(input('Enter obtained marks:'))
                        if Marks>T_Marks:
                            print('''\n"Please insert correct marks"''')
                        else:
                            l_Marks.append(Marks)
                            break
                except ValueError:
                    print('''\n"Please enter only number"''')
                else:
                    break
    l_T_Marks1=list(l_Marks)
    l_Marks1=l_Marks.copy()
    l_Subjects1=l_Subjects.copy()
    print(" _________________________________________________________________________")
    print("|                                                                         |")
    print("|                               Subjects                                  |")
    print("|_________________________________________________________________________|")
    print("|            Component             |                 Marks                |")
    print("|__________________________________|______________________________________|")



    for i in list(l_Marks):
        print(f"|              {l_Subjects.pop(0)}                   |           {l_Marks.pop(0)}/{l_T_Marks.pop(0)}                           |")
        print(f"|__________________________________|______________________________________|")

    print(l_Marks,l_T_Marks,l_Subjects)
    print(l_Marks1,l_Subjects1,l_T_Marks1)
    Sum_Marks=(sum(l_Marks1))
    Sum_T_Marks=(sum(l_T_Marks1))
```

Comment: happy to help :)